# Halbach array possible shapes?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Looking at images on the web most hallbachs are either rings or blocks but I have seen a couple pictures of what look to be rectangles or pyramids.  They are just illustrations though and maybe they're known as stelter arrays .  I'm wondering if an array could be made using LONG rectangles or pyramids with the same or similar results as blocks.
It'd be much easier to make for me